# Is there a way to ping a local IP address using flutter?

Tags: flutter, networking, dart, ping

I want to check if a specific device is connected to my network or not. I have the ip address of that device. I am unable to find a way to ping that device using flutter app. 
The goal here is to check if a particular device is connected to local network or not by pinging the device. 
Can you help?

Answer (score 9):

Use this,

```
import 'dart:io';
Socket.connect(IPADDR, PORT, timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)).then((socket){
       print("Success");
       socket.destroy();
     }).catchError((error){
       print("Exception on Socket "+error.toString());
     });
```

Comment: Flutter Socket uses TCP. Ping is based on ICMP. This is incorrect.

Comment: But this serves the main purpose of the OP : "I want to check if a specific device is connected to my network or not."

Answer (score 8):

There is a package available called [dart_ping](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ping) which allows you to ping IPs, but it hasn't been updated in some time.

Alternatively there is a package called [ping_discover_network](https://pub.dev/packages/ping_discover_network) that allows you to explore that network that your device is in. I haven't personally experimented with this one.

I've done some experiments with other packages to try to reproduce pinging, but the best result has been with the `dart_ping´ package:

```
import 'package:dart_ping/dart_ping.dart';

var pings = await ping('google.pl');

pings.listen((ping) {
  print(ping.time.inMilliseconds);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have tried this package along with some others. This one doesn't even get inside ping.listen

Comment: It's possible that the package no longer complies with the current version of the Flutter and Dart SDKs.